# concatenate numbers with operators as separator

Tags: php

I've a date in this format `1 Feb 2013` and I want to transform it to `2013-2-1`. Here the `php` code that I used but unfortunately it do a minus operation instead of concatenation!

```
  $first_format = "1 Feb 2013";
  $explode_date = explode(' ', $first_format);
  $final_format = $explode_date[2] . '-2-1';
```

This give `2010` as result not `2013-2-1`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please check [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Could you post your actual code?

Comment: Actually, the code works if you replace $date with $first_format.

Comment: Your value is in variable `$first_format` but you are exploding `$date`

Comment: Sorry I copied mal :)

Comment: Ok then, just place a `$` before `final_format`. Your code should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functions, specifically the [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method:

```
$first_format = "1 Feb 2013";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j M Y', $first_format);
echo $date->format('Y-n-j');

// Or to store the date in the final format:
$final_format = $date->format('Y-n-j');
```

Comment: @HocineBen Can you elaborate? `$final_format` should be a string (both in my code and in yours)

Comment: Sorry I've done a mistake, your solution work fine, but! why when I added this line `echo '<script>alert( '.$final_format.' )</script>';` the alert shows me `2010`?

Comment: You need double quotes in your alert, $final_format is a string.

Comment: If you inspect the source code, you'll see that the generated JavaScript code is `alert(2013-2-1);`. Since these are numbers in JavaScript, the expression will be evaluated algebraically and thus alert the computed value of `2010`. You need to enclose the JS string in quotation marks: `echo '<script>alert("' . $final_format . '");</script>`;. Also, be aware of [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) when echoing things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make the date string to time using [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) then format it with [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$first_format = "1 Feb 2013";
$final_format = date("Y-n-j",strtotime($first_format));
```

Answer (score 1):

see if this works

```
$first_format = "1 Feb 2013";
$explode_date = explode(" ", $first_format);
$final_format = trim($explode_date[2]) . " " . "-2-1";
echo $final_format;
```

Comment: yes it's working! thanks, but I think the first solution is more easier to understand.

Comment: yeah..i also think its better than mine